# QR Scanner npm library throwing errors for chrome

Tags: node.js, npm, promise, qr-code, barcode

I am using the library `https://github.com/felipenmoura/qr-code-scanner` to implement scanning of the QR codes. I am facing two problems -

1. Google chrome throws the following error whenever I click the button to trigger. The library works fine on Safari.

`Uncaught (in promise) OverconstrainedError {name: "OverconstrainedError", message: "", constraint: "facingMode"}constraint: "facingMode"message: ""name: "OverconstrainedError"__proto__: OverconstrainedError`

2. The camera feed doesn't work for mobile phones (both safari and chrome). It opens the camera, and doesn't show the live feed, instead it keeps on showing a **static image**

I am not sure if this is the best library for QR code scanning. My aim is to implement a button that triggers the camera, scans QR,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/306Cs.png) and puts the scanned string into the input field.

My code is -

```
<script src='../scanner.js'></script>

<script>
    function tryIt () {
        window.QRScanner.initiate({
            match: /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{16,18}$/,
            onResult: function (result) {
              console.info('DONE: ', result);
              document.getElementById("memberno").value = result;
              },
            onError: function (err) { console.error('ERR :::: ', err); },
            onTimeout: function () { console.warn('TIMEDOUT'); },
        });
    }
</script>
```

and the button is -

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-info" value='Scan QR' onclick='tryIt()' type="button" id="button-addon1">Scan QR</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is still looking for an answer to the best library for QR code scanning-

I found this library  [ScanThng](https://github.com/evrythng/scanthng.js) to be pretty decent in terms of image scanning, camera feed scanning, etc.